Why is this expression evaluation to undefined, even though debugging it shows the correct value?
I have this code in my .ts file:
fileUpload(file:UploadedFile){
    var imagesource = `data:${file.Type};base64, ${file.Data}`;
    this.srcPreview = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imagesource);
}

When an image is first uploaded imagesource always evaluates to "data:image/png;base64, undefined". However, if I add a breakpoint before the end of the function and enter data:${file.Type};base64, ${file.Data} into the DevTools console I get "data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...[rest of the data]".
If I then upload another image, the first image appears in the preview. The component is declared as
<img [src]="srcPreview">

Why is ${file.Data} evaluating to undefined at runtime even though debugging it shows the correct value, and why does uploading a second image cause the first image to appear?

How is the fileUpload() function being called?

I am not sure if it is relevant or not, but I don't think you can have a space after the comma.

@Pointy
Its called through a parent function when the fileUploaded event fires on the input element.
(fileuploaded) -> uploadEventHandler($event) -> fileUpload(file)

@deltasxb you should edit that contextual code into the question because that is almost certainly where the problem is.

The reason your code works when you debug it is almost certainly because the debugging activity introduces a delay that allows an asynchronous operation to complete.

@Pointy Thank you! Adding a setTimeout fixed it!

Don't use setTimeout. It is a very bad and unreliable approach. The problem is that your function was executed before the file was available in the input. As a result, you see that the input is empty, but after a small delay (while you are in the debugger), you have a file in it. It would help if you triggered your function like yourFileInput.addEventListener('change', yourHandler).

@RAllen I refactored it to wait on the file input change event and I removed the setTimeout. Thanks for the advice.

Solved by refactoring to correctly listen to the event that was up the call stack of the offending method. The method was executing before a call in uploadEventHandler($event) could complete.

Check Function Call: Ensure that the fileUpload function is being called with the correct parameter. Verify that the file object being passed to the function contains the Type and Data properties.
Verify Property Existence: Before accessing the Type and Data properties of the file object, check if they exist to avoid errors. You can use optional chaining (?.) or nullish coalescing (??) operators to handle cases where the properties may be undefined or null
var imagesource = `data:${file?.Type};base64, ${file?.Data}`;

